# ¿como crear una función para obtener el nombre del mes y numero de mes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Saludos, quisiera saber si alguien tiene una función o sabe como crear un store procedure en SQL SERVER que permita obtener el nombre y numero de mes y almacenarlo en una tabla temporal para posterior uso. No es necesario de una fecha determinada por el momento. Es decir:

```
Mes              Numero_Mes
Enero                1
Febrero              2
Marzo                3
Abril                4
Mayo                 5
```

...

Gracias de antemano

Comment: La verdad no entiendo bien el uso que quieres darle a la tabla. Si necesitas una tabla calendario, entonces no es necesario un stored procedure, porque deberías crearla una vez. Si necesitas obtener el nombre y número del mes desde un campo que sea date o datetime, entonces existen funciones de sistema que hacen eso

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, esas funciones si las uso. Es decir, crear una función donde tu creés la tabla temporal, en ella insertar el mes y numero del mes, como les comentaba. No a partir de un campo, si no desde 0

Comment: @Ric_hc T-SQL te provee varias funciones para fecha, para obtener una parte específica puedes usar [DATENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) en SQL Server 2008 o [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-pe/library/hh213505.aspx) en SQL Server 2012. Pero de tu pregunta, si ya tienes definido una tabla para que estar creando una tabla temporal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La verdad es que aún no entiendo muy bien el uso que le darás a esta tabla, pero hacer esto en SQL Server es bastante sencillo. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, pero quizás la más rápida y simple es:

```
SET Language 'Spanish'; -- Para configurar el idioma de la función DATENAME

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,number,'20170101')) Mes, number + 1 Numero_Mes
INTO #Meses
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND number <= 11;
```

Comment: No estaría demás especificarle el uso de [SET LANGUAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx), en caso lo tenga configurado en ingles y él lo quiera en español.

Comment: @Davlio Puede ser. No lo agregué porque el op dice que ya utiliza estas funciones, por lo que me imagino que lo conoce. De todas formas, lo voy a agregar para futuros usuarios, gracias

Comment: Hola Lamak, una pregunta, ¿no estaría de más `INTO #Meses`? Sin esa línea se obtiene la información del número de mes y su respectivo número :)

Comment: @Flxtr claro, pero por eso pregunté al op para qué necesitaba esto. Dice que lo necesita como tabla temporal, por eso lo puse

Comment: @Lamak ah muy bien! no había leído ese comentario ;)

Comment: A veces es dificil explicar como te lo imaginas, sin embargo, realmente tu respuesta(Lamak) ya me dio idea de lo que realmente necesito. Muchas gracias a todos por sus repuestas y comentarios, siempre hay alguien a quien acudir en este lugar para apoyarnos. Por mi parte, se puede cerrar la pregunta.